# C++ Loader Lock Error

Tags: c++, dll, hook

I am writing\compiling a DLL that(currently) only exports a blank function.  Source code:

DLLMain.cpp-

```
LIBRARYEXPORT LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(
int code,
WPARAM wParam,
LPARAM lParam
){



    return 0;


}
```

Everything is okay so far, and here is my DLLMain.h-

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#define LIBRARYEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)



LIBRARYEXPORT LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(
    int code,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
);
```

I plan to use this DLL with windows hooks to detect key presses, but when I call LoadLibrary from a separate executable, it returns with a runtime error saying

"DLL 'C:\Users\Orin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\winmain\Debug\winmain.dll' is attempting managed execution inside OS Loader lock. Do not attempt to run managed code inside a DllMain or image initialization function since doing so can cause the application to hang."

That's great, but here's the catch: I'm not running any code at all in my KeyboardProc function, and I don't even have a DllMain routine

What I've tried(and hasn't worked):

- Disabling CLR in project properties
- Removing my "DllMain" routine
- Using '#pragma unmanaged' when declaring functions

Suggestions and comments are really appreciated!

Comment: Debug + Exceptions, expand the "Managed Debugging Assistants" node, untick LoaderLock.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried that, and then it comes up with a runtime error saying that I am attempting to run MSIL code during native code initialization.   :-/

Comment: Clearly you are doing something very wrong, it is utterly unclear what that might be.  Start again and do *not* pick the project template from the CLR node this time.  Use the "Win32 Project" template to create an unmanaged DLL.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That fixed it.  I forgot that I used the Common Language Runtime support when I first created the library.

Answer (score 0):

**Found Answer:**

When using Visual Studio, you must not choose a CLR Library project. Instead use the "Win32 Project" template.  I can't believe I missed that!